# No puedo poner un dato con valor null en una tabla de null mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Tengo un problema, tengo una tabla con unos campos not null, y un par de campos que puede tener valores nulos, el problema es cuando quiero subirle data , solo me cargan las filas que tengan todos los valores, y las filas que tienen campos vacìos no los carga. Se supone que si no tiene la opcion de not null, puede tomar valores nulos. Este es el codigo de mi base de datos, el problema lo tengo con la tabla caja insumos:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema pizzahutalmacenbd
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema pizzahutalmacenbd
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;
USE `pizzahutalmacenbd` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`guiaremision`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`guiaremision` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`guiaremision` (
  `idGuiaRemision` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `FechaEntrega` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGuiaRemision`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`tipoinsumo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`tipoinsumo` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`tipoinsumo` (
  `idTipoInsumo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Tipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTipoInsumo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`unidad`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`unidad` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`unidad` (
  `idUnidad` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Unidad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUnidad`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`insumos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`insumos` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`insumos` (
  `idInsumos` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `VidaUtil` INT NULL,
  `Descongelamiento` INT(100) NULL,
  `TipoInsumo_idTipoInsumo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Unidad_idUnidad` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `precioUnitario` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idInsumos`),
  INDEX `fk_Insumos_TipoInsumo_idx` (`TipoInsumo_idTipoInsumo` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Insumos_Unidad1_idx` (`Unidad_idUnidad` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Insumos_TipoInsumo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TipoInsumo_idTipoInsumo`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`tipoinsumo` (`idTipoInsumo`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Insumos_Unidad1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Unidad_idUnidad`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`unidad` (`idUnidad`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenbaja`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenbaja` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenbaja` (
  `idOrdenBaja` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOrdenBaja`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`responsablecocina`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`responsablecocina` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`responsablecocina` (
  `idResponsableCocina` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Apellidos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idResponsableCocina`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordendescongelado`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordendescongelado` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordendescongelado` (
  `idOrdenDescongelado` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `ResponsableCocina_idResponsableCocina` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOrdenDescongelado`),
  INDEX `fk_OrdenDescongelado_ResponsableCocina1_idx` (`ResponsableCocina_idResponsableCocina` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_OrdenDescongelado_ResponsableCocina1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ResponsableCocina_idResponsableCocina`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`responsablecocina` (`idResponsableCocina`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenpedido`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenpedido` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenpedido` (
  `idOrdenPedido` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOrdenPedido`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ubicacion`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ubicacion` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ubicacion` (
  `idUbicacion` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Lugar` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUbicacion`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`cajainsumo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`cajainsumo` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`cajainsumo` (
  `idCajaInsumo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `FechaVencimiento` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Stock` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `Insumos_idInsumos` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `OrdenBaja_idOrdenBaja` INT(11) NULL,
  `GuiaRemision_idGuiaRemision` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `OrdenPedido_idOrdenPedido` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `OrdenDescongelado_idOrdenDescongelado` INT(11) NULL,
  `Ubicación_idUbicación` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `CantidadBaja` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCajaInsumo`),
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_Insumos1_idx` (`Insumos_idInsumos` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_OrdenBaja1_idx` (`OrdenBaja_idOrdenBaja` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_GuiaRemision1_idx` (`GuiaRemision_idGuiaRemision` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_OrdenPedido1_idx` (`OrdenPedido_idOrdenPedido` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_OrdenDescongelado1_idx` (`OrdenDescongelado_idOrdenDescongelado` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_Ubicación1_idx` (`Ubicación_idUbicación` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_GuiaRemision1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`GuiaRemision_idGuiaRemision`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`guiaremision` (`idGuiaRemision`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_Insumos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Insumos_idInsumos`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`insumos` (`idInsumos`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_OrdenBaja1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrdenBaja_idOrdenBaja`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenbaja` (`idOrdenBaja`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_OrdenDescongelado1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrdenDescongelado_idOrdenDescongelado`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordendescongelado` (`idOrdenDescongelado`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_OrdenPedido1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrdenPedido_idOrdenPedido`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordenpedido` (`idOrdenPedido`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_Ubicación1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Ubicación_idUbicación`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ubicacion` (`idUbicacion`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordensalida`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordensalida` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordensalida` (
  `idOrdenSalida` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `ResponsableCocina_idResponsableCocina` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Turno` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOrdenSalida`),
  INDEX `fk_OrdenSalida_ResponsableCocina1_idx` (`ResponsableCocina_idResponsableCocina` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_OrdenSalida_ResponsableCocina1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ResponsableCocina_idResponsableCocina`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`responsablecocina` (`idResponsableCocina`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`cajainsumo_has_ordensalida`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`cajainsumo_has_ordensalida` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`cajainsumo_has_ordensalida` (
  `CajaInsumo_idCajaInsumo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `OrdenSalida_idOrdenSalida` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CajaInsumo_idCajaInsumo`, `OrdenSalida_idOrdenSalida`),
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_has_OrdenSalida_OrdenSalida1_idx` (`OrdenSalida_idOrdenSalida` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_CajaInsumo_has_OrdenSalida_CajaInsumo1_idx` (`CajaInsumo_idCajaInsumo` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_has_OrdenSalida_CajaInsumo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CajaInsumo_idCajaInsumo`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`cajainsumo` (`idCajaInsumo`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CajaInsumo_has_OrdenSalida_OrdenSalida1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrdenSalida_idOrdenSalida`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`ordensalida` (`idOrdenSalida`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`dias`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`dias` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`dias` (
  `idDias` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Dia` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDias`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`demanda`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`demanda` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`demanda` (
  `Insumos_idInsumos` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Dias_idDias` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Demanda` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Insumos_idInsumos`, `Dias_idDias`),
  INDEX `fk_Insumos_has_Días_Días1_idx` (`Dias_idDias` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Insumos_has_Días_Insumos1_idx` (`Insumos_idInsumos` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Insumos_has_Días_Días1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Dias_idDias`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`dias` (`idDias`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Insumos_has_Días_Insumos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Insumos_idInsumos`)
    REFERENCES `pizzahutalmacenbd`.`insumos` (`idInsumos`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: si realizas un insert en un campo not null debe ir algo de datos, ingresa al menos un valor digamos si es campo numerico cero o -1 un espacio en texto o valor que puedas identificar como nulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Te lo explico a través del siguiente ejemplo para que veas como
>   manipular tanto columnas `NULL` como `NOT NULL`

Tenemos la siguiente estructura de una tabla

```
CREATE TABLE demo(
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  age INT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. El campo `name` es `NOT NULL` por lo tanto siempre va a exigir se ingrese un valor
2. El campo `email` es `NULL` por lo tanto puede quedar vacio o le puedes asignar un valor por defecto
3. El campo `age` es `NULL` pero para que no quede vacío le asigne un valor por defecto, que quiere decir que si un usuario no ingresa nada entonces la columna toma el valor de `0`

**EJEMPLO 1**

No voy a insertar ningún valor para `email` y para `age`entonces la estructura de mi query debe ser la siguiente

```
INSERT INTO demo(name)
VALUES
("Alfredo");
```

Y si hago un `SELECT` debería obtener esto

```
SELECT * FROM demo;

name     email  age
Alfredo         0
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

Como no le asigne ningún valor a las últimas dos columnas, entonces tampoco las invoque al momento de hacer el `INSERT`

**EJEMPLO 2**

```
INSERT INTO demo(name, email)
VALUES
("Alfredo", "alfa@mail.com");
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

Esta vez si invoco 2 columnas en el `INSERT` por que le daré un valor a `email`pero como a `age` le dejaré el valor por defecto entonces no la coloco en la sentencia

Mi resultado si hago un `SELECT` debería ser

```
SELECT * FROM demo;

name    email          age
Alfredo alfa@mail.com   0
```

**EJEMPLO 3**

Esta vez le asignaré un valor personalizado a cada columna de las 3 existentes por lo tanto si las coloco en la sentencia de `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO demo(name, email, age)
VALUES
("Alfredo", "alfa@mail.com", 12);
```

Si hago un `SELECT` mi resultado debería verse así

```
SELECT * FROM demo;

name    email           age
Alfredo alfa@mail.com   12
```